# notation about real integral over contour

Tags: calculus

A super stupid question: Is there a simple notation for the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})d\theta$$

I am tempted to writ something like

$$\int_{\mathcal{K}} f(z)dz$$

where $\mathcal{K}$ is the unit circle. But I know that this usually means complex integral which is actually different. But I really wanted to have some succinct notation for it instead of writing $e^{i\theta}$ everywhere.

Any thought? Thanks!

Comment: Well, $dz=i e^{i \theta} d \theta$ on the unit circle, so you could write $-i e^{-i \theta} dz$. Not sure how convenient that is, though.

Comment: Why don't you keep it that way? I don't see any best notation.

Comment: because my $f$ could be fairly complicated -- therefore it's a bit annoying to alway write $z = e^{i\theta}$..